# i have a userform in excel which i want to convert to an addin or menu item in excel 2003

Tags: excel, vba

i have wriiten a small vba code(userform & modules associated) for concatenating files in a user inputed folderpath. Currently i have this placed in personal.xls and everytime after opening excel i press ALT+F11 and go to the userform and run it (press F5).

I want this userform to be placed in as an addin or menu item in excel (available for all spreadsheets).

I know i need to assign a macro to a menu-item i add, but i have many subs (both in userform & modules associated) and not have instantiated my userform anywhere. i don't know which of these subs i need to assign to menu-item.

**MAIN GOAL:** is i wan't a menu item (or addin) which when i click pops up the userform. (afterwards running same as when i ran it from visual basic editor).

**THINGS TRIED:** i tried copying the userform & modules to a new project and saving it as an excel addin (.xla file) and placed the addin in excel add-ins folder. I have selected the addin from Tools>Addins option in excel. But, i think this way i was not able achieve what i needed as i don't see any new option/menu-item added to excel.

*Thanks in advance*

ps: I'm new to vba and just started working on it a week ago, so give me more detail in your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it right with add-in but in order to use your code you need to add menus, check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830502/en-us) out.

Comment: You're right, the link you sent to oficial microsoft was not easy to follow and generic. I found [this](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=427#instr) which was exactly what i wanted.